# How do I give tkinter labels equal dimensions?

Tags: python, tkinter

The labels are currently side by side which is what I want.  However each label's width is different. Is there a way to make each label have the same width?

Also is there a method that allows the labels to the have equal measurements and simultaneously fill all the way up to 250?

Here is my current code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("250x50")
w = Label(root, text="Label UNO", bg="red", fg="white")
w.pack(side=LEFT)
w = Label(root, text="Label2", bg="green", fg="black")
w.pack(side=LEFT)
w = Label(root, text="Label DREI", bg="blue", fg="white")
w.pack(side=LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

you should try checking tkinter's [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) on pack:

check if this is what you are looking for:

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("250x50")
w = Label(root, text="Label UNO", bg="red", fg="white")
w.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
w = Label(root, text="Label2", bg="green", fg="black")
w.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
w = Label(root, text="Label DREI", bg="blue", fg="white")
w.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Fill argument basically fills the parent container.

Expand argument will use to additional remaining space.

Also be sure to take a look at tkinter weight, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847313/what-does-weight-do-in-tkinter) is an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use key word arguments `width`, and `height` with a `tk.Label`

```
import tkinter as tk

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("250x50")

    label_frame = tk.Frame(root)

    w = tk.Label(label_frame, text="Label UNO", bg="red", fg="white", width=8, height=2)
    w.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    w = tk.Label(label_frame, text="Label2", bg="green", fg="black", width=8, height=2)
    w.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    w = tk.Label(label_frame, text="Label DREI", bg="blue", fg="white", width=8, height=2)
    w.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    label_frame.pack(expand=True)

    root.mainloop()
```

[image]

#### Notes:

- `tkinter is imported as tk` in order to keep the namespace tidy.
- The `tk.Labels` are included in a `tk.Frame`, so once this is built,
  you do not have to worry about it until you pack the frame in your
  GUI.
- The units for width and height are in "text units" when the label
  contains text.

Answer (score 1):

**To make the labels width the same**, just add the `width` option to the `label`

e.g. `width=10` this will specifies how much space, in character widths.

if you want to apply the same width to multiable labels, store the width value in a variable, lets say `label_w = 10`

so your code might look like this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("250x50")
label_w = 10
w = Label(root, text="Label UNO", bg="red", fg="white", width=label_w)
w.pack(side=LEFT)
w = Label(root, text="Label2", bg="green", fg="black", width=label_w)
w.pack(side=LEFT)
w = Label(root, text="Label DREI", bg="blue", fg="white", width=label_w)
w.pack(side=LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

***simultaneously fill all the way up to 250***

this depend on how many labels you'll create, lets say `window_width = 250` and `labels_all = 3` then the `width` option will be `width = window_width/labels_all`
also, if you don't write a `geometry` values, the window size will automatically fit to labels.

**if your window is simple enough**, you might consider using the Packer Option `expand` as in `expand=1`, also include the `fill` option if your label has color, fill Legal values: 'x', 'y', 'both', 'none'.

for more information, check [label-options](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#label-options), [packer-options](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#packer-options)