# How to align widgets in a grid with tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, widget, tkinter-layout

I am trying to align a label in the center of the window with two buttons under it, also centered. I have been googling and looking on here to figure out how to do it and I have found grid to be helpful but it is not doing what I expect. It works as I would expect if I put each of the widgets in a different row and column but if I put them in different rows and the same column, they just stay aligned left. What am I doing wrong with grid? Also, any suggestions on how I can improve the code overall would be appreciated.

I left out the LoadedMachine and CreateMachine classes because I don't feel they are needed. If they would be helpful, I can edit the question to add them.

```
class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, LoadedMachine, CreateMachine):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
            frame.config(bg='white')

        self.show_frame('StartPage')

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

        welcome_label = tk.Label(self, text='Welcome', bg='green', fg='white', font=('Verdana', 80))
        welcome_label.grid(row=0, column=1)

        loadButton = tk.Button(self, text='Load an existing state machine', command=lambda: controller.show_frame('LoadedMachine'))
        loadButton.config(highlightbackground='green', font=('Verdana', 18))
        loadButton.grid(row=1, column=1)

        createButton = tk.Button(self, text='Create a new state machine', command=lambda: controller.show_frame('CreateMachine'))
        createButton.config(highlightbackground='green', font=('Verdana', 18))
        createButton.grid(row=2, column=1)    


if __name__ == '__main__':
app = App()
app.title('Cognitive State Machine')
app.geometry('800x600')
app.mainloop()
```

This is what I get:

[image]

I want the buttons to be closer together and closer to the label.

Comment: It looks like you are giving a `weight` to the rows too - you don't have to.

Comment: Ahhh, gotcha. Thanks that fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion is to first add some background colors when you create your frames for troubleshooting.

```
class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self,bg="yellow")
        container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        ...
```

When you run this, you will see a bunch of yellow color, which means your `StartPage` frame is not filling up the space. So you need to change it:

```
for F in (StartPage,):
        page_name = F.__name__
        frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[page_name] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nesw")
        frame.config(bg='green')
```

Now you can see your background becomes green colour which means your `StartPage` frame correctly scales. Finally you can work on your labels:

```
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
    self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    ...
```

On why you need to add a weight to your columns, there is an excellent post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847313/what-does-weight-do-in-tkinter).

Comment: Thank you this helped a bunch. Except in the for F in (StartPage,): loop if I change it to frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True), it displays everything I have for all the frames without hitting a button to actually switch to another frame. How do I fix this?

Comment: Without the other two pages, I am not sure how you want your frames to show. But you can use `grid` as well and set the weight accordingly even for your frames.

Comment: I want to switch frames entirely when I click either the loadButton or createButton and only show the widgets that are on that frame.

Comment: I have edited the answer. In that case you need to set the `weight` on your `container` frame as well.

Comment: Awesome, I really appreciate it! Works like a charm.

Comment: One more problem. There is too much space between the label and the first button. Also too much space between the two buttons themselves. How can I make them closer to the label and each other?

Comment: Well i overlooked that you start your column index with 1 instead of 0. In that case,  `self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` in your StartPage frame.

Comment: I have that but they are still far apart. I have updated my code and added a picture of what I am getting. What am I doing wrong to make them so far apart?

Answer (score 0):

Add padding to the grid to align it how you want

You can add padx or pady according to your need

```
loadButton.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)
```

[Helpfull link to further play with grid layout](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)

Also instead of 'lambda' you could use 'partial' as we need to call the function from the command function and define it there.