# Not able to view tkinter form in python2

Tags: tkinter, pycharm, python-2.x

I'm creating UI of a form using **Tkinter** in **Python2** where IDE is **PyCharm**.

**Following is the code for the reference:-**

```
from Tkinter import *;

root = Tk()

root.geometry("400x100")

#adding the header label of the tool.
myheaderTitle = Label(root,text="myForm",bg="lime green",font="Calibri 16 bold",width="400")
myheaderTitle.pack()

button_1 = Button(root,text="Select File")
button_1.grid(row=0,column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

I'm successful in running the above code, but the form is not visible whenever I add below two lines of code.

```
button_1 = Button(root,text="Select File")
button_1.grid(row=0,column=0)
```

What could be the problem with these lines?

Comment: Cannot mix grid() and pack() inside same container.

Comment: How can we make the grid to take up full space

Comment: @BBRK To make **grid** take up "full space", you need to use `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` on your container. Check this [link](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@FrainBr33z3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10165734/frainbr33z3) and [@acw1668](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5317403/acw1668) comments, I was able to create my UI using the grid system in **Python2**.

I used following reference link(s) to understand the grid system.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/45850468/10456127
- https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html

**Below is the code for reference: -**

```
from Tkinter import *;

root = Tk()

root.geometry("400x100")

#adding the header label of the tool.
myheaderTitle = Label(root,text="myForm",bg="lime green",font="Calibri 16 bold",width="400")
myheaderTitle.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=(N, S, W, E),padx=5, pady=5,columnspan=2)

button_1 = Button(root,text="Select File")
button_1.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=(N, S, W, E),padx=5, pady=5)

button_2 = Button(root,text="Select Another File")
button_2.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=(N, S, W, E),padx=5, pady=5)

root.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps someone.