# Resizing frames in main window to fit the window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I have the menu frame on the left side and the main container on the right side but when I fire it up I only see them in a small box inside the main window.

How can I make the frames fit the window no matter what size it is?

[image]

Code:

```
class GUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title("GUI Project")
        # self.resizable(0, 0)
        menu = tk.Frame(self, relief="solid")
        container = tk.Frame(self, relief="ridge")
        menu.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=4, sticky="nsew")
        container.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        menu.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
        container.columnconfigure(1, weight=0)

        self.frames = ["Menu", "FutureFeature2", "TestPing", "FutureFeature3", "FutureFeature"]

        self.frames[0] = Menu(parent=menu, controller=self)
        self.frames[1] = FutureFeature2(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[2] = TestPing(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[3] = FutureFeature3(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[4] = FutureFeature(parent=container, controller=self)

        self.frames[0].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[1].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[2].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[3].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[4].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(1)

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        print(frame)
        frame.tkraise()
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5, rowspan=5, sticky="nsew")

class Menu(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Ping Test", bg="royalblue2",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(2))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="FutureFeature", bg="dark violet",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(4))
        buttun3 = tk.Button(self, text="FutureFeature", bg="pale goldenrod",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(1))
        button4 = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", bg="gray40",
                            command=lambda: self.terminate())

        button1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        button2.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        buttun3.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        button4.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    def terminate(self):

        path = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/desktop/Gui-Skeleton'

        try:
            os.rmdir(path)
        except OSError as err:
            print(f"Error Deleting tmp folder! {err}")

        exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    path = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/desktop/Gui-Skeleton'

    try:
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            pass
        else:
            os.mkdir(path)

    except OSError as err:
        print(f"[!] Operation failed! {err}")

    app = GUI()
    app.geometry("800x600")
    app.mainloop()
```

.....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: The code that is in the question won't run for several reasons. Please try to provide code we can run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific problem that you're asking about is due to the fact you are putting `menu` and `container` in the root window using `grid` but you haven't given any rows or columns in the root window a weight. Therefore, both `menu` and `grid` will use as little space as necessary.

A general rule of thumb is that when you use `grid`, you should give at least one row and one column a positive weight so that there is no unused space. You are failing to do that in the root window. For more information on grid weights see [What does 'weight' do in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847313/what-does-weight-do-in-tkinter)

The solution is simple: make sure that you've given at least one row and one column a positive weight in the root window:

```
self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

That being said, I would recommend using `pack` for `menu` and `container` since they are the only widgets directly in the root window. `pack` is generally better than `grid` when laying out widgets in row or column, if for no other reason that you don't have to take the extra step of assigning weights.

```
menu.pack(side="left", fill="y")
container.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)
```