# How does tkinter's grid_columnconfigure / row_columnconfigure work?

Tags: python, tkinter

I saw the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847313/what-does-weight-do-in-tkinter) question, and I wondered how does tkinter know which configurations should apply to what Frame?

The code that's used in the answer is the following:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x100")

f1 = tk.Frame(root, background="bisque", width=10, height=100)
f2 = tk.Frame(root, background="pink", width=10, height=100)

f1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
f2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

So I think my main question is how does tkinter know that the first `grid.column_configure` should apply to the first `f1 = tk.Frame()`?

Comment: because it was referenced by 0. So column "0" contains "f1" and has the weight of 0.

Comment: see number `0` in  `f1.grid(column=0, ...)`  and `root.grid_columnconfigure(0, ...)` - it means the same column. Important is also `root` in both `f1 = tk.Frame(root,...)` and `root.grid_columnconfigure(0, ...)`

Comment: Makes a lot of sense now, thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I think my main question is how does tkinter know that the first grid.column_configure should apply to the first f1 = tk.Frame()?

It doesn't know that, because it doesn't apply to `f1`. Both calls to `columnconfigure` in your code applies to the root window. It knows this because that's the window it is called on (`root.grid_columnconfigure...)`)

If you wanted it to apply to `f1`, you would call `f1.grid_columnconfigure...`.

It *affects* `f1` because you're calling `columnconfigure` on column zero and `f1` is in column zero.