# Tkinter buttons and entry alignments are changing?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am learning & working to create GUIs with python functions. but when creating buttons and text entry using the grid(), below the buttons alignments are changing.

before showing text entry,

[image]

after showing text entry,

[image]

Comment: Their allignments aren't changing, the grid size is changing and the objects inside are acting accordingly (by not changing...)

Comment: @Max, thank you. now i did understand that. but i don't know how show the text entry without affecting  grids. more over pack() options are not suitable to me

Comment: @Mathan you could find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63014842/how-to-stretch-cell-horizontally-using-grid-in-tkinter/63015055#63015055

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding a wide element to a narrow column, so the column expands to fit the entry.

In your case you probably want to add `columnspan=2` (or 3, or 4, depending on what you want to happen) when you add the entry to the display.