# Tkinter scroll main frame containing others frames

Tags: tkinter, canvas, scrollbar, frame

Python 3.8.5 on Windows 10, Tkinter

I would like to place different frames (each of them contain texts) in a bigger frame (the main frame), and allow to scroll the main frame in order to see all the frames inside.
So I place the main frame in a canvas, and I use the scrollbar to scroll the canvas which contains the main frame.
However, the scrollbar doesn't work, nothing happen when I use it, and I have no access to all the frames inside the main frame.

The second thing I don't understand is that I use frame.pack_propagate(False) to avoid that all the frames inside the main frame automatically resize to their content, but they do it anyway. Why ?

Thanks for the help !

```
from tkinter import *

def on_configure(event):canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

def accueil():

    global canvas
    
    canvas=Canvas(root)
    scrollbar=Scrollbar(root,command=canvas.yview)
    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    canvas.bind("<Configure>",on_configure)
    frame=Frame(canvas,bg="orange",width=canvas.winfo_reqwidth(),height=canvas.winfo_reqheight())
    canvas.create_window((0,0),window=frame)
    
    frame_nouveaute_1=Frame(frame,bg="red",width=300,height=150)
    frame_nouveaute_1.pack_propagate(False)
    frame_nouveaute_1.place(y=0)
    l=Label(frame_nouveaute_1,text="- Nouveauté 1",font=25,bg="red").grid(row=0)
    l=Label(frame_nouveaute_1,text="   . xxxxx",font=25,bg="red").grid(row=1)
    l=Label(frame_nouveaute_1,text="   . yyyyy",font=25,bg="red").grid(row=2)
    l=Label(frame_nouveaute_1,text="   . zzzzz",font=25,bg="red").grid(row=3)
    
    frame_nouveaute_2=Frame(frame,bg="green",width=300,height=150)
    frame_nouveaute_2.pack_propagate(False)
    frame_nouveaute_2.place(y=frame_nouveaute_1.winfo_reqheight()+10)
    l=Label(frame_nouveaute_2,text="- Nouveauté 2",font=25,bg="green").grid(row=0)
    l=Label(frame_nouveaute_2,text="   . xxxxx",font=25,bg="green").grid(row=1)
    l=Label(frame_nouveaute_2,text="   . yyyyy",font=25,bg="green").grid(row=2)
    l=Label(frame_nouveaute_2,text="   . zzzzz",font=25,bg="green").grid(row=3)
    
    frame_nouveaute_3=Frame(frame,bg="blue",width=300,height=150)
    frame_nouveaute_3.pack_propagate(False)
    frame_nouveaute_3.place(y=frame_nouveaute_1.winfo_reqheight()+10+frame_nouveaute_2.winfo_reqheight()+10)
    l=Label(frame_nouveaute_3,text="- Nouveauté 3",font=25,bg="blue").grid(row=0)
    l=Label(frame_nouveaute_3,text="   . xxxxx",font=25,bg="blue").grid(row=1)
    l=Label(frame_nouveaute_3,text="   . yyyyy",font=25,bg="blue").grid(row=2)
    l=Label(frame_nouveaute_3,text="   . zzzzz",font=25,bg="blue").grid(row=3)
    
    canvas.place(y=25)
    scrollbar.pack(side="right",fill="y")

root=Tk()
root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d"%(500,350,10,10))

accueil()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a scrollbar to a group of widgets in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085696/adding-a-scrollbar-to-a-group-of-widgets-in-tkinter)

Comment: To your second question, you use the geometry manager place, pack_propagate ist for the packer, please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63536506/13629335

Comment: Yes I found, by placing my different frames directly in the canvas, in place to use a main frame.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the links !!!