# Python Tkinter grid functions ignored

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, widget, tk-toolkit

I feel like I am missing something stupidly obvious here - surely the widgets should just be positioned along the top of the root window, but they completely ignore the `.grid()` function.

When I printed the `grid_size()`, it returned `(0,0)`. Why?!

Any help greatly appreciated :)

```
title = tk.Label(root, text="Enter a city below")
title.grid(row=0, column=0)
title.pack()

e = tk.Entry(root)
e.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
e.pack()

current_clicker = ttk.Button(root, text = "Current forecast", command=current)
current_clicker.grid(row=0, column=2)
current_clicker.pack()

hourly_clicker = ttk.Button(root, text = "By hour", command=hourly)
hourly_clicker.grid(row=0, column=3)
hourly_clicker.pack()

minute_clicker = ttk.Button(root, text = "By minute", command=minute)
minute_clicker.grid(row=0, column=4)
minute_clicker.pack()

daily_clicker = ttk.Button(root, text = "Daily", command=daily)
daily_clicker.grid(row=0, column=5)
print(daily_clicker.grid_size())
daily_clicker.pack()
```

Comment: Try removing `.pack()`. its not necessary to say so after saying, `.grid()`, thats the only weird stuff i see here

Comment: Never mix grid and pack in the same frame.

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63536506/13629335

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe all you have to do is remove either `pack()` or `grid(..)` method. It is not recommended to mix `pack()` and `grid()`, as it might erase the effect of the other and lead to such errors.

I recommend to get rid of `pack()` as `grid(...)` is a more orderly way of managing widgets, compared to `pack()`.

Tiny example:

```
hourly_clicker = ttk.Button(root, text = "By hour", command=hourly)
hourly_clicker.grid(row=0, column=3)

minute_clicker = ttk.Button(root, text = "By minute", command=minute)
minute_clicker.grid(row=0, column=4)
```

Hope it solved your doubts, if any more errors, do let me know

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Only one geometry manager can manage a widget at a time. So exactly like the title of the question is saying, when you call `.pack()` after calling `.grid(...)`, the effects of `grid(...)` are ignored.
For any given widget, you must only use one, and you need to be consistent with all widgets that have the same parent.

Answer (score 0):

`pack`, `grid` and `place` are the 3 methods available for placing a widget. `tkinter` refers to these as "geometry managers". Each of these provides a unique way to position and scale widgets.

- `pack` will dock your widget to a defined or available edge
- `grid` behaves like a table
- `place` allows you to define an arbitrary position (and size)

An individual widget cannot have more than one geometry manager attached to it, and parents cannot contain widgets that alternate between `pack` and `grid`. This means (for example), if you have a `Frame` full of widgets that use `pack`, none of those widgets can use `grid`, and vise-versa. `place` is not subject to this limitation and can be used anywhere.