# Anchor not applying in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

i put a check button in a Frame. The "side" of the frame is right.
I specify my check button to be on anchor 'center' but it goes on the right. Do you know how to solve this? Thank you

```
from tkinter import *

fenetre= Tk()
cadreoptions=Frame(fenetre,width=100,height=70,borderwidth=2)
cadreoptions.pack(side=RIGHT)

statusnegatif=IntVar()
negatifbutton= Checkbutton(cadreoptions,text='Négatif',variable=statusnegatif)
negatifbutton.pack(padx=5,pady=2,anchor='center')

fenetre.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *

fenetre= Tk()
cadreoptions=Frame(fenetre,width=100,height=70,borderwidth=2)
cadreoptions.pack(side=RIGHT,expand=1)

statusnegatif=IntVar()
negatifbutton= Checkbutton(cadreoptions,text='Négatif',variable=statusnegatif)
negatifbutton.pack(padx=5,pady=2)

fenetre.mainloop()
```

Your frame holding your label and where ever your frame is going the label will go with it. So `expand=1` makes your frame *resizing*.
The anchor is "center" by default, so it is not necessary.

[more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536505/how-do-i-organize-my-tkinter-appllication/63536506#63536506)

Comment: Thank You so much!

Comment: Just click the right grey check next to my answer. :D

Comment: You was so fastthat I could'nt check it yet!