# Removing a textvariable from a widget in tkinter

Tags: tkinter, widget

After already assigning a textvariable to a widget, how do I remove it? `widget.config(textvariable=None)` just isn't working. Couldn't find anything on google or here.

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: An alternative to removing the widget all together cause it messes up the grid. All the `grid_propagate(0)`'s in the world couldn't help me, so I figured I'll just remove the textvariable and empty the text, but nothing happens so I'm thinking there's some special way to do that.

Comment: are you familiar with the `grid_forget()` method. I think you have a layout problem not with your variable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536505/how-do-i-organize-my-tkinter-appllication/63536506#63536506

Comment: I am. It's just that if I do that, the entire layout goes to hell. No matter what I do. `rowconfigure(n, weight=x)` and `grid_propagate(0)` just don't help. It's as if tkinter is not behaving as promised.

Comment: It does if you know how to do it. If you could write a Question about it I would answer you, but need to see in what kind of context you are to make valid points.

Comment: You mean a post new Question? Or just comment the code here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222457/discussion-between-atlas435-and-vl3005).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign your variable to an empty string to achive this.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.StringVar()
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=var)
label.pack()
print(f"var= {label['textvariable']}")
label.config(textvariable='')
print(f"var= {label['textvariable']}")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: As you can see in my example it works. Show me a minimal exampel of your code

Comment: It didn't work the way you wrote it, but after adding `text=''` to the config method, it did. :) Thank you!! Couldn't edit my original comment cause of a false click on the "save edit" button.....