# Cannot see frame in tkinter python

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter, frame

hey there i was trying to make a gui using tkinter the following is the code that is used by me.The problem is there are no errors and the program execute and i will see the root but there is no frame.before adding button i was able to see frame but after adding button the frame disappears and i can only see button please help

```
    from tkinter import*
    from tkinter import ttk
    root=Tk()
    root.title("STUDY")
    style=ttk.Style() 
    style.configure("custom.TFrame",background="black")
    frame=ttk.Frame(root,style="custom.TFrame")
    frame.pack()
    frame.config(height=100,width=100)
    ttk.Button(frame,text="CLICK ME").pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: After `root.title("STUDY")` add `root.geometry("100x100")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The geometry management of tkinter is characterized by this Quote
> here:
>
> By default a top-level window appears on the screen in its natural
> size, which is the one determined internally by its widgets and
> geometry managers.

Your frame behave in the same way. If the frame contains nothing it get a width and height of 0, thats why you cant see it.

A way arround is to use either `pack_propagate` or `grid_propagate` it depends on what you intend to use in this frame.

Another unusally way would be to create a second frame in that frame and give it a width an height, the outerframe will check the width and height of the inner frame and stick to it. [See](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63191526/13629335)

there can be additional ways like for the geometry manager `pack` the options `fill` and `expand`.

[For more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536505/how-do-i-organize-my-tkinter-appllication/63536506#63536506)

Comment: i added root.geometry("100x100") but the problem still exist.

Comment: the problem is when i add a button before that i could see but after adding button i cannot see it

Comment: add `frame.pack_propagata(0)` below `frame.pack()` and see what happens

Comment: Now it works thanks for the help.can you please explain me why this happens in windows because i am taking a course on python and i followed exactly the same code my mentor used but he doesnt face any issues he is using it in mac.is this a problem only with windows.thanks again

Comment: Please read my answer carfully. As I already said, **tkinter** calculates the *natural size* of each *master* this can be a frame or a window or toplevel, it dosent matter. Also check out the link that I have posted there can be found a lot for beginners. At least https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/828183

Comment: @SandyaguR I added an additional way, maybe he was using these options.