# Frame not showing up

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm just trying to get a red background for something i'm working on but for some odd reason (or maybe i'm being stupid) the frame just doesnt want to show up.
When i run the code below all i get is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezPUN.png)

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.geometry("1200x600")

main_frame = Frame(
    master,
    bg = "#FF0000"
)

main_frame.pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainloop()
```

When i try `main_frame.pack(fill="both")` all i get to see is [a single line of red pixels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBXSI.png).
Does anyone know what is happening to my frames and how to possibly fix this?
Sorry if i'm asking something really stupid. I am just starting out with Python.

Comment: You may intrested in a guid to [organize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536505/how-do-i-organize-my-tkinter-appllication/63536506#63536506) your widgets

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given the frame a size and there's nothing else in the frame, so it defaults to 1x1 pixel.

You can either give the frame a size, or use some of the `pack` options to force it to fill the window.

```
main_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```