# Tkinter space between widgets keeps growing

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to get a paned widget to grow with a form but whenever I pull the window down vertically, the gap between the paned widget and the status bar grows.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

pw = PanedWindow(root, orient='horizontal')

red = LabelFrame(pw, text='red')
Label(red, text='something', anchor='w').grid(row=1, column=1)

blue = LabelFrame(pw, text='blue')
Label(blue, text='anything', anchor='w').grid(row=1, column=1)

pw.add(red, stretch='always')
pw.add(blue, stretch='always')

status = Label(root, text='Status', relief=SUNKEN)

pw.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)
status.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=True, fill=X)

root.mainloop()
```

Is there a way of stopping the gap between the status bar and the bottom of the window and the gap between the status bar and the paned widget from growing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve your issue I configured this line:

```
status.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=False, fill=X,anchor='n')
```

For more information [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536505/how-do-i-organize-my-tkinter-appllication/63536506#63536506).