# How to dynamically resize window with Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
root= tk.Tk()
root.title('Quick Googling')
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()

entry1 = tk.Entry (root) 
canvas1.create_window(200, 140, window=entry1)
canvas1.config(background="#8FB1CC"

button1 = tk.Button(text='Search Google', bg = "blue")
canvas1.create_window(200, 180, window=button1)
```

I want the colour of my window and the entry and button to utilise all the space when the window's size is changed.

Comment: your code doesn't do anything ?, see [ask] a question, and produce a [mcve]

Comment: There are several ways to achive that. The first question for me is, why do you use a canvas here? Would you mind to use a frame?

Comment: I don't have any preference to canvas, if frames are better suited I would prefer them.

Comment: You realize your code is not runnable right?

Comment: Just set the root background color to whatever you want? Like, `root.config(bg='#8FB1CC')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a frame the geometry mangers of tkinter is doing the job for you see:

```
import tkinter as tk

root= tk.Tk()
root.title('Quick Googling')
myframe = tk.Frame(root)
myframe.pack(fill='both',expand=True)

entry1 = tk.Entry (myframe,background="#8FB1CC")
entry1.pack(fill='x')

button1 = tk.Button(myframe,text='Search Google', bg = "blue")
button1.pack(fill='both',expand=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Look on a [small overview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536505/how-do-i-organize-my-tkinter-appllication/63536506#63536506) I wrote over the basics.

> 1. fill stretch the slave horizontally, vertically or both expand The
> 2. slaves should be expanded to consume extra space in their master.

So what the above code does is to create a `frame` in its *natrual size*, this means it shrinks itself to the minimum space that it needs to arrange the children.

After this we use for the first time the `geometry manager` *pack* and give the options *fill*, which tells the frame to *stretch* and using the optional argument *expand* to consume extra space. Together they resize your frame with the window, since there is nothing else in it.

After that we create an `Entry` and using once again the method `pack` to arrange it with this geometry manager. We are using again the optional argument *fill* and give the value *'x'*, which tells the geometry manager to **stretch the slave/entry vertically**.

So the entry streches vertically if the frame is expandes.

At least we create a `Button` and using the known keywords, to let it resize with the frame.

Comment: How could I fill the length of it? The rest of it works.

Comment: @SamrathChadha are there open questions?

Comment: what are open questions exactly? I'm new to stackoverflow