# Orient and Organize Tkinter frames

Tags: python, tkinter, frame, frames

I would like to know how to create frames that align to grid and fill space I dictate. I am having a hard time grasping frame orientation within a window. I can make all the frames, but if I pack, they are all on left or in a line/on right. I played with that and decided on grid(). I set the window geometry and then use grid for frames. However, my frames all collapse down  to the top left or my initial frame fills the whole space and the other two squeeze in around the edges. I tried using window geometry of 1024 and 768, then allotting width and height for my first frame to be 512 and 384. Then setting the next two to have width 512 and height of 192. I also saw in other articles that weight is important and tried iterations of code to alter that, but was unsuccessful. Rowspan and columnspan helped me get the background colors to appear so that I could visualize the space being occupied by each.

Anyway, code is below:

````
class twinsplay:
    
    def __init__(self):
        #Window
        self.window =  Tk()
        self.window.geometry('1024x768')
        self.window.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.window.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        
        #window title
        self.window.title('Live Feed')
        
        #frames and labels
        self.frame_left = Frame(self.window, background='magenta')
        self.frame_left.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, rowspan=3, columnspan=3, sticky=NSEW)
        self.label_left = Label(self.frame_left, text = 'Weather Data', justify=LEFT)
        self.label_left.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=NSEW)
        
        self.frame_tr = Frame(self.window, background='green')
        self.frame_tr.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=5, pady=5, rowspan=3, columnspan=2, sticky=NSEW)
        self.label_tr = Label(self.frame_tr, text = 'Solar Data', justify = RIGHT)
        self.label_tr.grid(row=0, column=512, sticky=NSEW)
        
        self.frame_br = Frame(self.window, background='yellow')
        self.frame_br.grid(padx=5, pady=5, rowspan=2, columnspan=2, sticky=NSEW)
        self.label_br = Label(self.frame_br, text = 'News', justify = RIGHT)
        self.label_br.grid(row=0, column=512, sticky=NSEW)
        
        #main
        self.window.mainloop()
    ```
````

Comment: empty rows/columns have size `0` - so using `column=512` make no sense. If you have to move object then you may have to use `grid_rowconfigure/grid_columnconfigure` inside frames - `self.frame_left.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)`

Comment: I don't understand what result you expect. Maybe draw it (in any image paiter) and add to question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I organize my tkinter appllication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536505/how-do-i-organize-my-tkinter-appllication)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your problem.

Your `frames` use full size inside `window` but elements inside `frames` are collapsed. You may need to use  `grid_rowconfigure`/`grid_columnconfigure` also with `frame_left`, `frame_tr`, `frame_br` to resize elements in grid inside `frames`.

I move elements to rows an columns `0` because empty rows/columns have no size and there is no sense to put in column `512`

```
from tkinter import *

class twinsplay:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.window =  Tk()
        self.window.geometry('1024x768')
        
        self.window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        #window title
        self.window.title('Live Feed')


        #frames and labels
        self.frame_left = Frame(self.window, background='magenta')
        self.frame_left.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=NSEW)


        self.label_left = Label(self.frame_left, text = 'Weather Data', justify=LEFT, bg='red')
        self.label_left.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=NSEW)

        self.frame_left.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame_left.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # ---
        
        
        self.frame_tr = Frame(self.window, background='green')
        self.frame_tr.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=NSEW)
        
        self.label_tr = Label(self.frame_tr, text = 'Solar Data', justify = RIGHT, bg='green')
        self.label_tr.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

        self.frame_tr.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame_tr.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # ---
        
        self.frame_br = Frame(self.window, background='yellow')
        self.frame_br.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, columnspan=2, sticky=NSEW)
        
        self.label_br = Label(self.frame_br, text = 'News', justify = RIGHT, bg='yellow')
        self.label_br.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

        self.frame_br.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame_br.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        #main
        self.window.mainloop()
        
twinsplay()
```

[image]

---

But if you try to do something different then maybe you have to use `grid_rowconfigure`/`grid_columnconfigure` with other rows/columns - you can use it many times with different rows/columns.

---

**EDIT:**

[image]

```
from tkinter import *

class twinsplay:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.window =  Tk()
        self.window.geometry('1024x768')
        
        # left and right column will use the same size
        self.window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.window.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        
        # top and bottom rows will use the same size
        self.window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.window.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
                
        #window title
        self.window.title('Live Feed')

        #frames and labels
        
        # frame will use 2 rows 
        self.frame_left = Frame(self.window, background='magenta')
        self.frame_left.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=NSEW, rowspan=2)


        self.label_left = Label(self.frame_left, text = 'Weather Data', justify=LEFT, bg='red')
        self.label_left.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky=NSEW)

        self.frame_left.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame_left.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # ---
        
        self.frame_tr = Frame(self.window, background='green')
        self.frame_tr.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=NSEW)
        
        self.label_tr = Label(self.frame_tr, text = 'Solar Data', justify = RIGHT, bg='green')
        self.label_tr.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

        self.frame_tr.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame_tr.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # ---
        
        self.frame_br = Frame(self.window, background='yellow')
        self.frame_br.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, columnspan=2, sticky=NSEW)
        
        self.label_br = Label(self.frame_br, text = 'News', justify = RIGHT, bg='yellow')
        self.label_br.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

        self.frame_br.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frame_br.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        #main
        self.window.mainloop()
        
twinsplay()
```

Comment: I see that you configured the columns in each of the frames, I had not tried that. The output that you get is similar to what I am getting, but I want the Weather Data frame on the left and the solar data and news on the right. I wanted Weather data to take up the whole half and for the other two to stack and take up the right-half. But I keep getting that giant weather frame.

Comment: it would be simpler if you would draw layout (any image painter) and put in question. But probably you have to create two columns - first for wather, and second for other elements -  and use `grid_columnconfigure` for both - `grid_columnconfigure(9, weight=1)` grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)` and then they should have the same widths.

Comment: I put new example in answer

Comment: Thank you!
I will draw up the GUI 'looks-like' goal in paint, excel, or some other tool first in the future. 
 
I learned that the grids for the labels are within the frames, and that I was not applying the 'configure'  methods properly. 
I had a misunderstanding of how the columns and rows worked. I see now, that you create them and can place the frames into them. 
(I thought they magically existed and I just had to specify...wrong!)

Have a great night!