# How to do Layout Management in Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, layout

I have attached two images showing the layout that I am currently getting (Image 1) and the layout which I want (Image 2), **(Label 3 at position of GREEN BOX and Entry 1 at position of PURPLE BOX).** Can i get output as image 2 using `pack()` or do I need to either `grid()` or `place()`?

#### I am getting this layout:

[image]

#### I want this type of layout:

[image]

#### My code for Image 1 [I am currently getting]

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1000x700+0+0')
root.minsize('1000','700')

f1 = Frame(root, bd=5, relief=GROOVE, width=500, height=500)
f1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=30, pady=30)

f2 = Frame(f1, bg='pink', bd=5, relief=GROOVE)
f2.place(anchor=CENTER, relx=0.5, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8)

lbl_1 = Label(f1, text='Label 1',  bg='yellow', bd=2.5, relief=GROOVE,  font=('Times New Roman',20,'bold'))
lbl_1.pack(side=TOP, pady=5)

lbl_2 = Label(f2, text='Label 2',  bg='yellow', bd=2.5, relief=GROOVE,  font=('Times New Roman',20,'bold'))
lbl_2.pack(side=TOP, pady=5)

lbl_3 = Label(f2, text='Label 3', bg='yellow', bd=2.5, relief=GROOVE,  font=('Times New Roman',15,'bold'))
lbl_3.pack(pady=10)

txt_1 = Entry(f2, text='Txt 1', bd=2.5, relief=SUNKEN,  font=('Times New Roman',15,'bold'))
txt_1.pack(pady=10)

lbl_4 = Label(f2, text='Label 4',  bg='yellow', bd=2.5, relief=GROOVE,  font=('Times New Roman',20,'bold'))
lbl_4.pack(side=BOTTOM, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536505/how-do-i-organize-my-tkinter-appllication/63536506#63536506) usefull.

Comment: `grid()` seems like a more nice approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use `anchor="w"` in `.pack(...)` to move the label and entry to the left side and add horizontal margin using `padx`:

```py
...
lbl_3.pack(padx=30, pady=10, anchor="w")
...
txt_1.pack(padx=30, pady=10, anchor="w")
...
```