# Not able to get frames to fit to root

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
root.geometry("1000x750")
root.title("order recorder")
root.configure(background = "#399DAF")



def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()


f1 = Frame(root)
f2 = Frame(root)
f3 = Frame(root)
f4 = Frame(root)

for frame in (f1, f2, f3, f4):
    frame.grid(row = 0,column = 0 , sticky = 'news')
    

Button(f1, text='Go to frame 2', command=lambda:raise_frame(f2)).pack()
Label(f1, text='FRAME 1').pack()

Label(f2, text='FRAME 2').pack()
Button(f2, text='Go to frame 3', command=lambda:raise_frame(f3)).pack()

Label(f3, text='FRAME 3').pack(side='left')
Button(f3, text='Go to frame 4', command=lambda:raise_frame(f4)).pack(side='left')

Label(f4, text='FRAME 4').pack()
Button(f4, text='Goto to frame 1', command=lambda:raise_frame(f1)).pack()

raise_frame(f1)








root.mainloop()
```

Not able to get the frames to fit to root They keep going to the edge or hiding  , could you please post the code with explanation please I just started GUI in python

Comment: Try adding `root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` and `root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)` just after you create your `Tk()`

Comment: [Please take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536505/how-do-i-organize-my-tkinter-appllication/63536506#63536506)

Comment: @Atlas435 I don't think that is the problem here. OP's problem is that the frames don't expand to fill the whole window. OP is using `.grid` so they can put all of the frames in 1 stop and call `.tkraise()` on which ever frame they want to show.

Comment: @TheLizzard where do you think I do adress the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rows and columns by default are only as big as the largest item they contain. You need to tell tkinter what to do with any space that is unallocated, such as when the window is larger than its contents.

Since you are using `grid`, you can configure tkinter to allocate all extra space to row 0 and column 0, causing each to expand to fit the window.

```
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```