# How to insert a loop function into a label in Tkinter (self_updatable)

Tags: python-3.x, loops, tkinter

I have this loop that runs and changes x, how should I put it into a Tkinter label? Thanks in advance.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk() 

def x_loop():
    x = 0
    while x <= 100:
        time.sleep(2)
        x = x + 1
        
l = Label(root, text = x_loop).pack(pady = 20)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tkinter dosent like while loops, this is because a while loop dosent return to the mainloop till its finished and therefore you application isnt working during this time.

Tkinter provides for this the `.after(*ms,*func)` method and is used below.
Also for changing the text of a `tk.Label` you can go for several ways. I think the best way is to use the inherated option *textvariable*.

The textvariable needs to be a `tk.*Variable` and configures the `tk.Label` as soon as the *var* is set.

Check out the working example below:

```
import tkinter as tk

x = 0
def change_text():
    global x
    var.set(x)
    x +=1
    root.after(100,change_text)#instead of a while loop that block the mainloop

root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.StringVar()
lab = tk.Label(root, textvariable=var)
lab.pack()
change_text()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's much easer to just use `lab.config(text=<new text>)`

Comment: @MarkasPovilaika ~ Consider marking this as the correct answer if this answered your question correctly. Click [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/775796) to learn how :D

Comment: @TheLizzard thanks. Could you show a fully working example with the easier method?

Comment: @Atlas435 i am trying to pack lab with a x and y variable "lab = tk.Label(root, textvariable = var).pack(x=10,y=10)", however I get this error: _tkinter.TclError: bad option "-x": must be -after, -anchor, -before, -expand, -fill, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, or -side. Is there solution for that?

Comment: `.pack()` dosent uses *x* and *y* coordinates, `.place()` do. [Check out, for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536505/how-do-i-organize-my-tkinter-appllication/63536506#63536506)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `StringVar` as @Atlas435 did, you can use this simpler method:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def x_loop():
    global x
    if x <= 100:
        x += 1
        # Update the label
        label.config(text=x)
        # after 2000 ms call `x_loop` again
        root.after(2000, x_loop)

x = 0
root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text=x)
label.pack(pady=20)

# STart the loop
x_loop()

root.mainloop()
```