# How to pack 2 buttons at (one on the left, one on the right) the bottom of the screen in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to to place 2 buttons in the bottom-right and bottom-left of the screen so they stick when the window gets resized however when I anchor them and pack them they end up like shown below.
How do I fix this?

[image: display]

```py
if newbuttonthere == False:
    new_button = tk.Button(fightWindow, text="New", fg="black", command=newcharacter, font=("Courier", 20, "bold"))
    new_button.pack(anchor=W, side=tk.BOTTOM)
    new_button.configure(bg="grey")
if newbuttonthere == False:
    newM_button = tk.Button(fightWindow, text="New Monster", fg="black", command=newmonster, font=("Courier", 20, "bold"))
    newM_button.pack(anchor=E, side=tk.BOTTOM)
    newM_button.configure(bg="grey")
```

Comment: please add the code to the question

Comment: @saeedhosseini done sorry!

Comment: use a frame that you pack on the bottom side and put these widgets in that frame, then put them on right and left side

Comment: or actually anchor them both at `'s'` and put their sides as `'left'` and `'right'`

Comment: It seems like you are a beginner and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536505/how-do-i-organize-my-tkinter-appllication/63536506#63536506) could help you orientated.

Comment: @Atlas435 im not really a beginner at tkinter or python, im just tired xD

Comment: @Joshua6014 `.pack()` will stack the widgets on the side you instruct them, or by default it will be `tk.TOP`. In other words, it creates new *columns*. So its impossible to achive what you like with `.pack()` as long as you intend to use the same master. Use another *geometry manager*, I would suggest you to use `.grid()` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @Joshua6014 .pack() will stack the widgets on the side you instruct
> them, or by default it will be tk.TOP. In other words, it creates new
> columns. So its impossible to achive what you like with .pack() as
> long as you intend to use the same master. Use another geometry
> manager, I would suggest you to use .grid() in this case.

Using different masters:

```
mstr_one = tk.Frame(root)
mstr_two = tk.Frame(root)

mstr_one.pack(side='left')
mstr_two.pack(side='right')

lab_one = tk.Label(mstr_one,text='right bottom')
lab_two = tk.Label(mstr_two,text='left bottom')

lab_one.pack(side='bottom',anchor='e')
lab_two.pack(side='bottom',anchor='w')
```

Using grid instead of pack:

```
lab_one = tk.Label(root,text='right bottom')
lab_two = tk.Label(root,text='left bottom')

lab_one.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='e')
lab_two.grid(column=2,row=0,sticky='w')
root.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be using the fill attribute, the following way:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
root.configure(background='#01324a')

# Label frame will contain your two other widgets
labelframe = Frame(root, bg='pink')
item1 = Label(labelframe, text='Left', bg='yellow')
item2 = Label(labelframe, text='Right', bg='green')

labelframe.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
item1.pack(side='left')
item2.pack(side='right')

root.mainloop()
```

Fill will make the label expand horizontally, so it uses all the space in the assigned "row" rather than just the necessary.

I encourage you to check what would happen if you remove the fill attribute -> (pink will go behind the other widgets, as the space used will be the minimum needed)

Also, I suggest adding a frame in top of the bottom label, but it is not required.