# Tkinter - How to make button fill more than 1 column?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to know how can I place this button across 3 columns :

```
container.grid(columnspan=3, rowspan=5)

button_result = ttk.Button(container, text="Result").grid(column=(1,2,3), row=5)
```

I can only place it on column 1. What if I want to make it fill the space across column 1, 2 and 3 on row 5 ?

I didn't find the answer yet, still looking for it.

Thanks !

Comment: You are searching for `.grid(...columnspan=3,...)` [take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536505/how-do-i-organize-my-tkinter-appllication/63536506#63536506)

Comment: thanks @Atlas435 , but the container in which the button is "contained" already has 4 columns. Wouldn't that overwrite it?

Comment: as in the provided link stated *columnspan Insert the slave so that it occupies n columns in the grid.* It starts counting from your column. So it should look like this `.grid(column=4, columnspan=3, row=5)`

Answer (score 2):

By adding parameter `columnspan` you can "merge" multiple columns. Output will be centered button in merged columns. And by adding `sticky` parameter you can expand button to sides.

- `columnspan=3` - merge 3 columns (starting with selected)
- `sticky="we"` - expand button to the left and right sides (west, east)

e.g.

```
from tkinter import Label, Button, Tk

app = Tk()

l1 = Label(text="text")
l1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10)

l2 = Label(text="text")
l2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)

l3 = Label(text="text")
l3.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10)

btn = Button(text="Check")
btn.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="we")

app.mainloop()
```

Check [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_grid.htm).