# fill attribute of pack in tkinter is not working

Tags: python, tkinter, attributes

1. I am trying to keep the title in centre when resizing the window
2. I tried to change the label and to import * modules from tkinter for possible solution
3. Any help or hint is highly appreciated
4. following is the attached code:

```py
import tkinter as t

root=t.Tk()

root.geometry("1000x500")
'''Login/Register page '''

root.title("LOGIN PAGE")


bankLabel=t.Label(text="Bank of DINAGOD")
bankLabel.pack(fill='x')
bankLabel.place(x=475)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you are using place after you pack it, you unpack it automatically. To *fill* with place you need `place(... ,relx=1..)`. [Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536505/how-do-i-organize-my-tkinter-appllication/63536506#63536506)

Comment: @Thingamabobs did you mean `relwidth=1`? (which wouldn't be exactly filling anyways if that `x` coord was used)

Comment: @Matiiss my bad, yes I meant that. I'm not used to place anyway. Thanks for clearing this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use both `pack()` and `place()` function on the same widget. Use only `pack()` function to declare the positions of your widget.