# Why I'm not able to assign rows and columns in grid

Tags: python, tkinter

[Here is the SS of code with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdOcS.png)

```
Error: _tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack
```

When i change to

```
user.grid(row=0, column=0)
password.grid(row=1, column=0)

user.pack(row=0, column=0)
password.pack(row=1, column=0)
```

it is throwing an error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: bad option "-row": must be -after, -anchor, -before, -expand, -fill, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, or -side
```

[SS of Code with Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5GzF.png)

Comment: remove the screenshots and provide code and error message in text format

Comment: Screenshots do not allow us to cut and paste to try your code.  Paste text as *text*.

Comment: The error suggest exactly what is wrong with your code. `.pack()` simply dosent know the *optional argument* `row`. In addition, it makes little to no sense for you to use the geometry manager *grid* just to switch to *pack*. [You may find this helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536505/how-do-i-organize-my-tkinter-appllication/63536506#63536506)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't mix `pack` and `grid`.

> Warning: Never mix grid and pack in the same master window. Tkinter will happily spend the rest of your lifetime trying to negotiate a solution that both managers are happy with. Instead of waiting, kill the application, and take another look at your code. A common mistake is to use the wrong parent for some of the widgets.

I would say to choose the `grid` function because it is easier to choose where each widget goes. So, change `l1.pack()` to `l1.grid(row=0, column=0)` (Replace the 0's with the row and column you want to place it with).

For example:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk() 
root.geometry("700x400") # Title
root.title("Dance Admission Form") # Label
l1 = Label(text="Admission Form", font="Arial 15 bold")
l1.grid(row=0, column=0) 
user = Label(root, text="Username")
password = Label(root, text="Password")
user.grid(row=1, column=0)
password.grid(row=2, column=0) 
root.mainloop()
```

or a centered version:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk() 
root.geometry("700x400") # Title
root.title("Dance Admission Form") # Label
l1 = Label(text="Admission Form", font="Arial 15 bold")
l1.grid(row=0, column=0)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
user = Label(root, text="Username")
password = Label(root, text="Password")
user.grid(row=1, column=0)
password.grid(row=2, column=0) 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: But l1 is my Heading of my GUI so how can i place in the middle when i use .pack while packing it will place it in the middle and while using .grid it will placed it by defalt in 0th row

Comment: @KrunalDhaygude Take a look at my edited answer.