# How to align widgets/columns in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am struggling to align some widgets in my tkinter project.  I want the label at the top of the window to be center aligned and the combobox to be under that label and right aligned.

I've been trying for a little while, but still can't get it working.  I would really appreciate pointers from anyone who can tell where I've gone wrong.  I've attached my code and a screenshot to better illustrate the issue.

```
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

from ctypes import windll
windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(1)

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Solve Times Tracker")
root.configure(background="gray")
root.geometry("1200x800")

tk.Label(root, text="Solving time logger", font='ariel 17', anchor="w").grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="N")

options = ["one","two","three"]
combotext = tk.StringVar()
combotext.set('Please select your name')

select = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=combotext, state="readonly", font='ariel 17', width=25)

select.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="E", pady=20)

select['values'] = ("one","two","three")


def callback_function(event):
    print('You selected:', combotext.get())

root.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', callback_function)



root.mainloop()
```

[image: image explanation]

Thanks.

Comment: Your problem should be solved by using `.grid_columnconfigure` and assigning `weight`s appropriately. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71171950/tkinter-how-to-align-widgets-to-the-right-independently-of-the-length-of-widgets/71172483#71172483) answer to understand better.

Comment: Thanks, that helped with the drop-down menu, but my title label is still towards the left.  I'm going to try to play around with it a little more.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, it is easier to use `.pack()` instead of `grid()`:

```py
tk.Label(root, text="Solving time logger", font='arial 17').pack()
...
select = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=combotext, state="readonly", font='arial 17', width=25)
select.pack(anchor='e', pady=20) # put at the right side
...
```

If you insist on using `grid()`:

```py
...
# make column 0 use all the horizontal space
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

tk.Label(root, text="Solving time logger", font='arial 17').grid(row=0, column=0)
...
select = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=combotext, state="readonly", font='arial 17', width=25)
select.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="e", pady=20)
...
```