# How can i change frame.pack() into a form of grid, so i can use grid throughout my program

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-entry

I keep getting the error message of "cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack" - which means i cant use pack and grid together. I dont know how to change frame.pack() into a form where i can use grid.

```
def __init__(self, master):

    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.pack()

    root.geometry("800x600")
    root.title("www.heathhighschool.co.uk/local/secure/management%system")
    root.iconbitmap("HeathIcon.ico")
   
    username = Label(frame, text="Username:").grid(row=1, column=0)
    username_entry = Entry().grid(row=1, column=1)
    
    passw = Label(frame, text="Password:").grid(row=2, column=0)
```

Comment: _"which means i cant use pack and grid together."_ - just to be clear, you can use them both in an application, you just can't use them both for widgets that have the same parent. It's quite normal, if not an actual best practice, to use both in medium to large UIs.

Comment: I would suggest that you shouldn't call `frame.pack()` in this code, as it means that this code needs to know how it's parent is managing other widgets. The code that creates this object should be responsible for calling `grid` or `pack` or whatever else it wants.

Answer (score 0):

`Entry().grid(row=1, column=1)` Entry has no positional argument, such as `root` or `frame` which determinates the master and if no positional argument is given `tk.Tk()` (*root*) is set by default.

To solve your issue, either use a different master for your `Entry` or use `frame.grid()`

---

Also note that you can have in each master a nested layout, within you can choose to use `.pack()` or `.grid()`.

See my answer here for a [basic knowledge of tkinters geometry management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536505/how-do-i-organize-my-tkinter-appllication/63536506#63536506).

---

In addition, your assignment will become `None` since `.grid()` returns `None`, while you want to keep a reference that is returned by `Widget()`:

```
username = Label(frame, text="Username:")
username.grid(row=1, column=0)
```