# How do i resize this labelframe in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, ttk, tkinter-text

So I tried to make this `labelframe` wider by using the basic `width` and `width` option.

Here's my given minimal code.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

app = Tk()
app.resizable(False, False)
mainLayout = ttk.Frame(app, padding=10)
mainLayout.grid()
settings = ttk.Labelframe(mainLayout, text="Settings", padding=10, width=1000)
settings.grid()
ttk.Label(settings, text="Length limit (in seconds)").grid()
ttk.Spinbox(settings, from_=60, to=600, width=4).grid()
app.mainloop()
```

minimalized preview:
[image: what am i trying to do]

used in application:
[image]

i want to get this `labelframe` little bit bigger and make the inside centered, But i had no knowledge to do so, Any help will apreciated!

Comment: The Frame is displayed in its natural size, means the minimum space that is required. If you want to change that there are [different approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63536506/13629335) to achieve this. You need to show us your code with the chosen geometrymanager and options you have chosen. Also in order to get a qualified solution you would need to specify if you have more widgets and containers in mind that you wish to display besides the ones shown in your [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you just want to have a `main_frame` in the app. For simplicity I've used `.pack` with the options `fill` and `expand` with the constants `tkinter.BOTH` to stretch the widget in both (x,y) direction and `True` to consume extra space. (This is one of the reasons why wildcard imports are discouraged, you can be unaware of overwriting something, use `import tkinter as tk` instead). Same happens with the `LabelFrame`, you may could delete one of the containers, but that is up to you.

In `LabelFrame` I have configured the *grid* and gave the instruction that the column 0 should get the extra space with the *priority*/weight 1.

In addition, I gave your Spinbox a little bit more width, changed the size of the window and separated the constructor from the geometrymethod.

To get in touch with the geometry management in tkinter, you could play around with the [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63536506/13629335) (e.g. comment some out) and see what happens.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

app = Tk()
app.geometry('500x500')
app.resizable(False, False)
mainLayout = ttk.Frame(app, padding=10)
mainLayout.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=True)
settings = ttk.Labelframe(mainLayout, text="Settings", padding=10, width=1000)
settings.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=True)
settings.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
my_label = ttk.Label(settings, text="Length limit (in seconds)")
my_label.grid()
my_spinbox = ttk.Spinbox(settings, from_=60, to=600, width=20)
my_spinbox.grid()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: then how do i center 2 spinboxes?

Comment: @Bulieme I can not follow your comment. Do you want to add another spinbox or did I do something to your code?

Comment: no, i mean, if i had two spinboxes, how do i center them?

Comment: @Bulieme it depends what you mean by *center*, I could imagine different layouts. The simplest would be the option `row=number` to use in your grid.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/gsOb68F i tried but got this..

Comment: @Bulieme when I just copy and paste the code that is related to `my_spinbox` and name it `my_spinbox2` it aligns in the center. Did you specify the same master (e.g `settings`)

Comment: `my_spinbox = ttk.Spinbox(settings, from_=60, to=600, width=20)
my_spinbox.grid(row=1)
my_spinbox2 = ttk.Spinbox(settings, from_=60, to=600, width=20)
my_spinbox2.grid(row=1, column=1)` @Thingamabobs

Comment: Also yeah i put it on the same master

Comment: try: `my_spinbox2.grid(row=2, column=0)`. Remember column 0 gets the extra space. and in row 1 is your first spinbox.

Comment: I want it to go horizontal