# Arrange radio buttons horizontally using pack method in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

This is my first GUI attempt with python using tkinter and I cannot figure out what is the problem:

here is my  initial code:

```
from tkinter import *

root_app = Tk()
root_app.title("Test App")

#Question 1 - best car brand
v1 = StringVar()
v1.set(None)
Label(root_app, text="What is your favorite car barnd?\n", font=('Helvatical bold',16), fg='#ff0').pack()

r1 = Radiobutton(root_app, text='Mazda', value='Mazda', variable=v1).pack()
r2 = Radiobutton(root_app, text='BMW', value='BMW', variable=v1).pack()
r3 = Radiobutton(root_app, text='Ford', value='Ford', variable=v1).pack()

#Question 2 - best sports brand
v1 = StringVar()
v1.set(None)
Label(root_app, text="What is your favorite sports barnd?\n", font=('Helvatical bold',16), fg='#ff0').pack()

r1 = Radiobutton(root_app, text='Nike', value='Nike', variable=v1).pack()
r2 = Radiobutton(root_app, text='Adidas', value='Adidas', variable=v1).pack()
r3 = Radiobutton(root_app, text='Puma', value='Puma', variable=v1).pack()

root_app.mainloop()
```

It works but the radio buttons are shown vertically:

[image]

I tried to use `side='left'` configuration for `pack()` in my code:

```
r1 = Radiobutton(root_app, text='Mazda', value='Mazda', variable=v1).pack(side='left')
r2 = Radiobutton(root_app, text='BMW', value='BMW', variable=v1).pack(side='left')
r3 = Radiobutton(root_app, text='Ford', value='Ford', variable=v1).pack(side='left')
```

but I got a messy frame and cannot figure out how to fix it horizontally under each label:

[image]

Comment: You should take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63536506/13629335) to start with. As a hint, it is important to imagine the final GUI or at least you should have an idea of it. For example, you could stick to `.pack()` geometry and use frames where you pack them *left*, or you could switch to `.grid()` geometry management and work something out (e.g. columnspan).

Comment: `pack()` is better to keep all in one column or to keep all in one row. You may need to use `Frame` to keep radiobuttons in one row, and to keep this frame with other elements in one column

Comment: you don't need `\n` in label. If you want to create distance then better use `pady=` or `ipady=` in `pack()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pack()` is better to keep all in one column or in one row.

You may need to use `Frame` to keep `radiobuttons` in one row, and keep this frame with other elements in one column.

```
import tkinter as tk   # PEP8 `import *` is not preferred

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Test App")

# Question 1 - best car brand  # PEP8: one space after `#` (and two spaces before `#` if there is code before `#`)
v1 = tk.StringVar(root)
v1.set(None)
tk.Label(root, text="What is your favorite car barnd?").pack(pady=10, padx=10)

frame_1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame_1.pack()

tk.Radiobutton(frame_1, text='Mazda', value='Mazda', variable=v1).pack(side='left')
tk.Radiobutton(frame_1, text='BMW',   value='BMW',   variable=v1).pack(side='left')
tk.Radiobutton(frame_1, text='Ford',  value='Ford',  variable=v1).pack(side='left')

# Question 2 - best sports brand  # PEP8: one space after `#` (and two spaces before `#` if there is code before `#`)
v2 = tk.StringVar(root)  # you have to use other name for variable
v2.set(None)
tk.Label(root, text="What is your favorite sports barnd?").pack(pady=10, padx=10)

frame_2 = tk.Frame(root)
frame_2.pack(pady=(0,10))  # add pad only below

tk.Radiobutton(frame_2, text='Nike',   value='Nike',   variable=v2).pack(side='left')
tk.Radiobutton(frame_2, text='Adidas', value='Adidas', variable=v2).pack(side='left')
tk.Radiobutton(frame_2, text='Puma',   value='Puma',   variable=v2).pack(side='left')

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

You don't need `\n` in `Label`. Better use `pady` (or `ipady1`) in `pack()`

Using `r1 = Radiobutton(...).pack()` you assign `None` to `r1` because `pack()`/`grid()`/`place()` always gives `None`. You may skip `r1 =`  if you will no use `r1` later. Or you have to do it in two steps `r1 = Radiobutton(...)` and later `r1.pack()`

---

**EDIT:**

Eventually you could use `grid()` with `columnspan` for labels (to use 3 columns) but it looks little different because radiobuttons in the same column share width of cell. Besides when you use more radiobuttons then you have to change `columnspan`. With `Frame` you don't have to do this.

```
import tkinter as tk   # PEP8 `import *` is not preferred

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Test App")

# Question 1 - best car brand  # PEP8: one space after `#` (and two spaces before `#` if there is code before `#`)
v1 = tk.StringVar(root)
v1.set(None)
tk.Label(root, text="What is your favorite car barnd?").grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=10, padx=10)

tk.Radiobutton(root, text='Mazda', value='Mazda', variable=v1).grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Radiobutton(root, text='BMW',   value='BMW',   variable=v1).grid(row=1, column=1)
tk.Radiobutton(root, text='Ford',  value='Ford',  variable=v1).grid(row=1, column=2)

# Question 2 - best sports brand  # PEP8: one space after `#` (and two spaces before `#` if there is code before `#`)
v2 = tk.StringVar(root)  # you have to use other name for variable
v2.set(None)
tk.Label(root, text="What is your favorite sports barnd?").grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=10, padx=10)

tk.Radiobutton(root, text='Nike',   value='Nike',   variable=v2).grid(row=3, column=0)
tk.Radiobutton(root, text='Adidas', value='Adidas', variable=v2).grid(row=3, column=1)
tk.Radiobutton(root, text='Puma',   value='Puma',   variable=v2).grid(row=3, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]