# Why my ttk style won't apply to my Frame?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I've been fighting with ttk style for about 2 days right now, but nothing seems to work. I've tried a lot of different approaches, but I had no effect. Right now, I just want to see that the Frame that I'm trying to add to my App is working, could you please show me where is the problem?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Main window configuration
        self.title("Work Tracker")
        self.geometry("600x700")
        self.resizable(0,0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Styles
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure('TFrame', background='blue')

        # Logo frame
        frame = ttk.Frame(self, width=200, height=150)
        frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        frame.grid_propagate(False)
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nw')
        
        label = ttk.Label(frame, text ="WORK TRACKER")
        label.pack()



def main():
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: `frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nw')` instructs the frame to be in column=0, row=o and to stick in the corner north west. What you probably want is to stretch that frame. You could stretch it on the x-axis with `we` or y-axis with `ns` or in both with `nswe`. You may want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63536506/13629335). I've wrote this for beginners, but intermediate can look there as well. To be honest, I do look there first myself if I don't recall.

Comment: Oh my god, I can't believe I lost so much time because I misunderstood this option, thank you so much my dude <3