# tkinter inserting space between button and label with grid

Tags: python, tkinter

I want between button and label to be at minimum 6 rows of grid framework based. I put `ttk.Label(mainframe, text="enter  url ").grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=('N'))` row is one, and sticky which is North.

> *If the cell is larger than the widget, the sticky option specifies which side the widget should sticks to and how to distribute any extra
> space within the cell that is not taken up by the widget at its
> original size*.

And with button `button.grid(column=3, row=7, sticky=tk.S)` stiky to South, if there is space, and row start from 7. When you run you see that they are near each other like row =3 in button.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Your App crawler")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root)

mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=('N'))
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

feet = tk.StringVar()
feet_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=21, textvariable=feet)
feet_entry.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(tk.N),ipadx=100)
feet_entry.focus()

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="enter  url ").grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=('N')) #attention:row is 1

def crawler():

button = ttk.Button(mainframe, text="scrape", command=crawler)
button.grid(column=3, row=7, sticky=tk.S) #even though row is 7, and sticky equals 'S'
root.bind("<Return>", crawler)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children():
    child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)
root.mainloop()
```

Why it is so, and how to change the way I desire?
Nice resource for practice [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536505/how-do-i-organize-my-tkinter-appllication/63536506#63536506)

Comment: What do you mean `minimum 6 rows`? How big is a row? You have to have something in between rows for them to have spacing. You could try using weights and assign a weight to the empty rows to give them space

Comment: you mean by adjusting `root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)` this weight values I guess. I tried by 3 no effect

Comment: rows without widgets will have zero height. However you can use `.rowconfigure((3,4,5,6,7), uniform=1)` to override it.

Comment: can I put two label with background color same with main frame with width =3 each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from User @acw1668 helped to work out it;

`ttk.Label(mainframe).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=('N')) ttk.Label(mainframe).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=('N'))#?`

By putting two labels with row 3 and without text I managed to get 6 row space. Thanks for help

Comment: Use @username to attribute someone :)

Comment: I think, I did wrong answer, width should be  equal to 3 not row