# Why isn't my Python tkinter popup dialog showing up when I use grid instead of pack?

Tags: python, tkinter, dialog

I'm building a Python tkinter popup as a subclass of *simpledialog.Dialog* with nothing but specialized buttons. The body method only gives the dialog label and returns None.

The buttonbox method defines the buttons and the commands are fine. When I place the buttons with *pack*, everything works fine. But if I try to use *grid* instead, as I normally do in the body method of other dialogs, the dialog doesn't show at all though the app continues to run.

Is there a call I'm missing to make it appear?

The buttonbox methods has nothing except the button creations and placements. No other calls.

For several reasons, I prefer to use grid, not pack.

The basic structure is body, apply, and buttonbox plus the command methods. The same problem occurs if I *grid* a Label into the body.

Note: other questions are similar, but I think this is a buttonbox issue specifically.

---

```
from tkinter import simpledialog, Button, Tk, LEFT

class FooDialog(simpledialog.Dialog):

    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)

    __val = "mumble"
    
    @classmethod
    def get(cls):
        return FooDialog.__val
    
    def getResult(self):
        return FooDialog.__val
     
    def handle(self, which):
        if not which:
            FooDialog.__val = "jumble"
        self.destroy()
   
    def buttonbox(self):
        noButton = Button(self, text="Foo", width=10, command= lambda t=False: self.handle(t))
        noButton.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
   
    def body(self, master):
        self.title('Foo')    
        return None
    
    def apply(self):
        FooDialog.__val = self.getResult()
        

def foo():

    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    FooDialog(root)
    root.destroy()
    return FooDialog.get()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print( foo())
```

If I replace the grid call with:

```
    noButton.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

nothing will appear

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [mre], and read about [ask]. Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: Tkinter has no widget *ButtonBox*, how can it specifically related to this not existing widget? Your question lacks of details and a [mre]. There shouldn't be any other differences when using `grid`or `pack` except for geometrical placement. Does your widget hides behind any margins?

Comment: @Thingamabobs, buttonbox is a method of simpledialog.Dialog. It isn't a separate widget.

Comment: Are you subclassing [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/tkinter/simpledialog.py#L89) widget?

Comment: @Thingamabobs, yes, and overriding both body and buttonbox (and apply)

Comment: Can you share this class? Because it sounds like a mistake you've made somewhere along the line, but from the code you've shared I can't spot it. Or it might be because of recent changes in that particular module. As I said, can't tell from here.

Comment: @Thingamabobs here is the code. As it it runs, but replacing pack with the grid call fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When replacing `pack` with `grid` I get the following error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside .!foodialog which already has slaves managed by pack
```

and this is because of a little bit odd design decision of this rather old module.
They first `pack` a frame for the `body` *[1](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/tkinter/simpledialog.py#L127) in the scope of `__init__`, so you can't reach it easily but you can stick to the design *[2](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/tkinter/simpledialog.py#L165).

This means you will need to `pack` another frame within you can choose a different layout/geometry-manager.

```
from tkinter import simpledialog, Button, Tk, LEFT, Frame

class FooDialog(simpledialog.Dialog):

    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)

    __val = "mumble"
    
    @classmethod
    def get(cls):
        return FooDialog.__val
    
    def getResult(self):
        return FooDialog.__val
     
    def handle(self, which):
        if not which:
            FooDialog.__val = "jumble"
        self.destroy()
   
    def buttonbox(self):
        button_frame = Frame(self)
        noButton = Button(button_frame, text="Foo", width=10,
            command= lambda t=False: self.handle(t))
        noButton.grid(row=0, column=0)
        button_frame.pack()
   
    def body(self, master):
        self.title('Foo')    
        return None
    
    def apply(self):
        FooDialog.__val = self.getResult()
        

def foo():

    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    FooDialog(root)
    root.destroy()
    return FooDialog.get()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print( foo())
```

You might find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63536506/13629335) helpful.

Comment: Yes, creating the frame and later packing it, along with adding the buttons to the frame did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: @Buffy if you don't get any error, you might need to check your python version and update it. Because this error is as long as I code around and this is a few years now. Be aware that there is even an end for [security support in older versions](https://devguide.python.org/versions/)

Comment: That is a bit hard. I'm on an older mac using Eclipse and pydev. And the error didn't appear. Honestly though, I'm pretty sure I wouldn't have been able to interpret it correctly an would still need to ask. But it isn't for a critical app in any case. I'm working on materials for novices and Python isn't my native tongue.

Comment: @Buffy if you interested, you can join the [tkinter chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249491/tkinter) from time to time. If all you need is a little help to provide examples for students, it might be a better place to talk about related topics. I do not know everything, but I rate myself above average in *python* and *tkinter*.