# How to correctly assigning weights to columns in a Tkinter frame?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is what I am trying to achieve

[image]

Here is the code:

```
class GeometryFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        rectangle_1 = tk.Label(self, text="Rectangle 1", bg="green", fg="white")
        rectangle_1.grid(column=0, row=0, ipadx=10, ipady=10, sticky="EW")

        rectangle_2 = tk.Label(self, text="Rectangle 2", bg="red", fg="white")
        rectangle_2.grid(column=0, row=1, ipadx=10, ipady=10, sticky="EW")

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("600x100")
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.geo_frame = GeometryFrame(self)
        self.geo_frame.grid(column=0, row=0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

But I am getting this
[image]

How to fix this? (NOTE: I want to use `grid` and not `pack`).

I get the desired result if I remove the `GeometryFrame` class and place it's code to the `App` class.

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("600x100")
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        # self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        rectangle_1 = tk.Label(self, text="Rectangle 1", bg="green", fg="white")
        rectangle_1.grid(column=0, row=0, ipadx=10, ipady=10, sticky="EW")

        rectangle_2 = tk.Label(self, text="Rectangle 2", bg="red", fg="white")
        rectangle_2.grid(column=0, row=1, ipadx=10, ipady=10, sticky="EW")
```

Comment: You might find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63536506/13629335) useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify the `GeometryFrame` class to include the `columnconfigure` method for the desired column.

```py
import tkinter as tk

class GeometryFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        rectangle_1 = tk.Label(self, text="Rectangle 1", bg="green", fg="white")
        rectangle_1.grid(column=0, row=0, ipadx=10, ipady=10, sticky="EW")

        rectangle_2 = tk.Label(self, text="Rectangle 2", bg="red", fg="white")
        rectangle_2.grid(column=0, row=1, ipadx=10, ipady=10, sticky="EW")

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("600x100")
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.geo_frame = GeometryFrame(self)
        self.geo_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="NSEW")  # Add sticky="NSEW" to fill the available space

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

This is end result: [image: result]

The `self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` line is included in the `GeometryFrame` class to assign weight to the column, enabling it to expand and occupy the available space. In the `App` class, the grid method call for `self.geo_frame` is modified with the `sticky="NSEW"` parameter to ensure that the `GeometryFrame` widget completely fills the available space within the main window.

By implementing these changes, the `GeometryFrame` expands to occupy the entire width of the main window, while the Rectangle 1 and Rectangle 2 labels within their respective rows also expand accordingly.

Comment: Funny! `sticky` stole the show :)