# I can't seem to find from the highlighted padding is coming from in the following picture of the gui I am designing with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I am a beginner in tkinter and has been playing around with what I have learnt so far. The following is the code which I find is **only relevant to answer my question** and below that I have attached the picture of the gui I have got so far.

```
# Frame for the time spinners
timeFrame = tkinter.LabelFrame(mainWindow, text="Time")
timeFrame.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="new")

# Time spinners
hourSpinner = tkinter.Spinbox(timeFrame, width=2, values=tuple(range(0, 24)))
minuteSpinner = tkinter.Spinbox(timeFrame, width=2, from_=0, to=59)
secondSpinner = tkinter.Spinbox(timeFrame, width=2, from_=0, to=59)

hourSpinner.grid(row=0, column=0)
tkinter.Label(timeFrame, text=":").grid(row=0, column=1)
minuteSpinner.grid(row=0, column=2)
tkinter.Label(timeFrame, text=":").grid(row=0, column=3)
secondSpinner.grid(row=0, column=4)
timeFrame.config(padx=36)

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(mainWindow, width=50, height=50, bg="red")
canvas.grid(row=4, column=0)
```

[image: Picture Of the GUI I have so far]

Here I can not seem to understand from where the **padding between the label frame containing the time component and the red canvas** is coming from. **(I have highlighted the padding I am referring to in yellow using the snipping tool.)**

I feel like there should be no padding between the label frame and the red canvas and the canvas should start from somewhere around the label frame ends.

***I would be grateful if anyone could point me out from where this padding is coming from and how to make the canvas start from where the label frame ends?***

However, if anyone reading this question finds that he/she needs to look at the complete code in order to answer, I have attached the complete code I have typed to build this below,

```
try:
    import tkinter
except ImportError:  # Python2
    import Tkinter as tkinter

import os

mainWindow = tkinter.Tk()
mainWindow.title("Grid Demo")
mainWindow.geometry("640x480+320+125")

label = tkinter.Label(mainWindow, text="Tkinter Grid Demo")
label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)


mainWindow.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainWindow.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
mainWindow.columnconfigure(2, weight=3)
mainWindow.columnconfigure(3, weight=3)
mainWindow.columnconfigure(4, weight=3)

mainWindow.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainWindow.rowconfigure(1, weight=10)
mainWindow.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
mainWindow.rowconfigure(3, weight=3)
mainWindow.rowconfigure(4, weight=3)

fileList = tkinter.Listbox(mainWindow)
fileList.grid(row=1, column=0, rowspan=2, sticky="nsew")
fileList.config(relief="sunken", borderwidth=2)

for zone in os.listdir(r"C:\Windows\System32"):
    fileList.insert(tkinter.END, zone)

listScroll = tkinter.Scrollbar(mainWindow, orient="vertical", command=fileList.yview)
fileList.config(yscrollcommand=listScroll.set)
listScroll.grid(row=1, column=1, rowspan=2, sticky="nsw")

# Frame for the radio buttons
optionFrame = tkinter.LabelFrame(mainWindow, text="File Details")
optionFrame.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="ne")

rbValue = tkinter.IntVar()
rbValue.set(3)

# Radio Buttons
radio1 = tkinter.Radiobutton(optionFrame, text="Filename", value=1, variable=rbValue)
radio2 = tkinter.Radiobutton(optionFrame, text="Path", value=2, variable=rbValue)
radio3 = tkinter.Radiobutton(optionFrame, text="Timestamp", value=3, variable=rbValue)

radio1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
radio2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")
radio3.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="w")

# Widget to display the result
resultLabel = tkinter.Label(mainWindow, text="Result")
resultLabel.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="nw")

result = tkinter.Entry(mainWindow)
result.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="sw")

# Frame for the time spinners
timeFrame = tkinter.LabelFrame(mainWindow, text="Time")
timeFrame.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="new")

# Time spinners
hourSpinner = tkinter.Spinbox(timeFrame, width=2, values=tuple(range(0, 24)))
minuteSpinner = tkinter.Spinbox(timeFrame, width=2, from_=0, to=59)
secondSpinner = tkinter.Spinbox(timeFrame, width=2, from_=0, to=59)

hourSpinner.grid(row=0, column=0)
tkinter.Label(timeFrame, text=":").grid(row=0, column=1)
minuteSpinner.grid(row=0, column=2)
tkinter.Label(timeFrame, text=":").grid(row=0, column=3)
secondSpinner.grid(row=0, column=4)
timeFrame.config(padx=36)

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(mainWindow, width=50, height=50, bg="red")
canvas.grid(row=4, column=0)

mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: Delete `mainWindow.rowconfigure(3, weight=3)`. Change the last line before `mainloop` to `canvas.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="nesw")` in order to see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is rows' weight you configured. If you delete the lines:

```
mainWindow.rowconfigure(3, weight=3)
mainWindow.rowconfigure(4, weight=3)
```

the layout will look like you wanted to. For more info check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45850468