# Why wont my grid_columnconfigure work on this tkinter code?

Tags: python, tkinter

Just started learning tkinter and im tackling on grid management.
I set the a frame to have 1 weight on column 0, therefore I expected label1 to be stretched to the end of the frame, then label2 added on column 1 with the length relative to its text size.

expected output: https://gyazo.com/65cf907e2cdea07d08844bdc8c62c7b2

output: https://gyazo.com/3c9e9c9f86372e01e96283545387c51e

Heres my code:

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, *kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        frame_list = (MenuFrame,
                     )

        self.geometry("1024x768")
        self.frames = {}

        for F in frame_list:
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("MenuFrame")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class MenuFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.create_widgets(self)

    def create_widgets(self, parent):

        frame = tk.Frame(self, bg="white")
        frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        label1 = tk.Label(frame, text="Label one", bg="red")
        label2 = tk.Label(frame, text="Label two", bg="blue", fg="white")

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        label2.grid(row=0, column=1)
  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Abrar 
Thanks for the  comment, I'm actually looking for a way to stretch label1 using weight and not manually changing its width via the width parameter.

Comment: @Abrar, not quite, for more info on what im trying to do, check this question out!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847313/what-does-weight-do-in-tkinter
Basically, if the initial window width was 1000, and each label width was 100, I want labelone to cover 900, and then place labeltwo to cover 100. This being relative everytime you change the initial window width.

Comment: @Abrar the base frame.

Comment: @Abrar  its being used in line 37: tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
serves as a parent frame for MenuFrame so it inherits the qualities of the base frame when you MenuFrame is initialized

Comment: @Abrar Planning on using it once i solve this problem so I think thats beside the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are properly configuring the weight for `frame`. However, `frame` hasn't been properly configured to fill the window. Because of that, it's just barely wide enough for the two labels and thus the `weight` has  no effect.

Since `frame` seems to be the only widget inside the class `MenuFrame`, I would use `pack` instead of `grid` since it only requires one line:

```
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

If you prefer using `grid`, then you need to also configure the weight for its parent.

```
self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
```