# Getting error while achieving split screen in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to get the split screen, where if i click a button in the left screen then frame should be shown in the right screen. So i used Panedwindow with 2 different frames (rightframe and leftframe). Gave buttons in the leftframe (button1 and button2). If i click the button1 then Frame1 (class Frame1) should be shown in the rightframe and if i click the button2 then Frame2 (class Frame2) should be shown in the rightframe so used raiseFrame to change the frame accordingly but getting below error if i click the button.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk,Tk, BOTH, Menu
  
def raiseFrame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

class Main(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        
        m = PanedWindow(height=500, width=1000)
        m.pack(side=tk.RIGHT,fill = tk.Y)

        leftframe = Frame(m)
        m.add(leftframe)

        button1 =tk.Button(leftframe, text="first frame",command=lambda: raiseFrame(Frame1))                    
        button1.pack(side = tk.TOP, expand=1)
        
        button2 =tk.Button(leftframe, text="2nd frame",command=lambda: raiseFrame(Frame2))                   
        button2.pack(side = tk.TOP, expand=1)


        rightframe= Frame(m, bg="green")
        m.add(rightframe)


class Frame1(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        label = tk.Label(rightframe, text="1st FRAME").pack(side = tk.LEFT,fill = tk.BOTH) 
            

class Frame2(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        label = tk.Label(rightframe, text="2nd FRAME").pack(side = tk.LEFT,fill = tk.BOTH)
        
app = Main()
app.mainloop()
```

error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\New folder\GUI.py", line 23, in <lambda>
    button1 =tk.Button(leftframe, text="first frame",command=lambda: raiseFrame(Frame1))
  File "C:\Users\New folder\GUI.py", line 7, in raiseFrame
    frame.tkraise()
TypeError: tkraise() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Screenshot after changes:
[image]

Comment: You are calling `.tkraise` on the class instead of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't instantiated the class `Frame1` and `Frame2`, you are passing the classes directly and calling `tkraise` on them. You would have to first create their instances and stack them up.

```py
frame1=Frame1(rightframe)
frame1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nesw')
frame2=Frame2(rightframe)
frame2.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nesw')
```

Then pass the instances to the command

```py
command=lambda: raiseFrame(frame1)
command=lambda: raiseFrame(frame2)
```

Also, you haven't specified the `parent` argument in the `__init__` function and the `Label` should have the current frame (`self`) as the master and not `rightframe`.

```py
class Frame1(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        label = tk.Label(self, text="1st FRAME").pack(side = tk.LEFT,fill = tk.BOTH)
```

Additionally, I don't see a point in creating 2 different classes just for having a different text in the containing label, you can define a single class something like this

```py
class CustomFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, text=''):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        label = tk.Label(self, text=text)
        label.pack(side = tk.LEFT,fill = tk.BOTH)
```

And have 2 instances of it

```py
frame1=CustomFrame(rightframe,text='1st Frame')
frame2=CustomFrame(rightframe,text='2nd Frame')
```

**UPDATE**

Add the following to allow expansion (the concept of `weight` has been explained well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45850468/14094985))

```py
rightframe.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
rightframe.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. Its working but have a doubt.. sticky='nesw' isn't working, the label wont fill in the entire window.. is it possible to explain on that part. please find the attached screenshot. @AST