# Why doesn't the column width fill the frame using `weight` in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, pack

I have run in to a diffuctly where despite using the `sticky` and `weight` options from the `grid` and `columnconfigure` methods respectively, I am unable to make the column expand the entire width of my frame.

I have read through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847313/what-does-weight-do-in-tkinter) which explains things well, however I haven't had any luck. Below is a simplified example of my code, where the desired result can be achieved by uncommenting the lines using the `pack` method, which I'd like to replicate using the `grid` method as well.

```
import tkinter as tk

class myGUI(tk.Frame):

    class ScrollableFrame(tk.Frame):
        
        def __init__(self, parent):
            
            # Create scrollbar
            self.frame = tk.Frame(parent)
            self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.frame)
            self.yscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.canvas, orient='vertical', command=self.canvas.yview)
            tk.Frame.__init__(self, self.canvas)
            self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self, anchor='nw')

            # Configure scrollbar
            self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.yscrollbar.set)
            self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all')))

            # Pack scrollbar
            self.canvas.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)
            self.yscrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')

            # Configure placement
            self.pack = self.frame.pack
            self.place = self.frame.place
            self.grid = self.frame.grid

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.wrap = tk.LabelFrame(parent)
        self.myFrame = self.ScrollableFrame(parent)

        for i in range(50):
            tk.Button(self.myFrame, text='My Button - '+str(i)).pack()

        # self.myFrame.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')
        # self.wrap.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')
        self.myFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = 'news')
        self.wrap.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky = 'news')
        parent.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        parent.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        parent.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        parent.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()

    root.geometry('500x500')
    root.title('Scrollbar Test')
    myGUI(root)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Not related to your question: defining classes inside other classes is bad practice and should be avoided.

Comment: Good to know, you had commented on my previous post to include the scrollable frame code within a class and that's how I understood it. Will place the class outside the other one on my actual code.

Comment: To my knowledge it isn't possible to make widgets inside a scrolled canvas fill the width of the canvas. Try adding `width=27` to the `tk.Button(...)`. That will set the width of the buttons

Comment: I don't want the widgets inside the scrolled canvas to fill its width, but rather the scrolled canvas itself to fill the width of the main application window.

Comment: Try removing the `parent.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)`. Right now you aren't using the second column and that line forces the width to be split evenly between the 0th and 1st columns

Comment: ^^ yep, just realised my mistake...