# tkinter label inside frame of frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I am now practicing how dynamic the frame setting can be in tkinter.

For pure frame setting, it looks perfect:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyWindow: 
    def __init__(self, root):
        
        w_root = 1280
        h_root = 720
        root.title('My model')
        root.geometry(f"{w_root}x{h_root}")
        
        self.top_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=w_root, height=80, bg='grey')
        self.top_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=0, pady=5)
        self.main_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=w_root, height=640, bg='blue')
        self.main_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=0, pady=0) 
        self.left_frame = tk.Frame(self.main_frame, width=500, height=620, bg='red')
        self.left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)       
        self.right_frame = tk.Frame(self.main_frame, width=760, height=620, bg='yellow')
        self.right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
          

root = tk.Tk()
mywin = MyWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

However, when I tried to put a label in left_frame (frame inside main frame), the interface became strange:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyWindow: 
    def __init__(self, root):
        
        w_root = 1280
        h_root = 720
        root.title('My model')
        root.geometry(f"{w_root}x{h_root}")
        
        self.top_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=w_root, height=80, bg='grey')
        self.top_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=0, pady=5)
        self.main_frame = tk.Frame(root, width=w_root, height=640, bg='blue')
        self.main_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=0, pady=0) 
        self.left_frame = tk.Frame(self.main_frame, width=500, height=620, bg='red')
        self.left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)       
        self.right_frame = tk.Frame(self.main_frame, width=760, height=620, bg='yellow')
        self.right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
        
        
        self.lb_currdate = tk.Label(self.left_frame, text='my lable1:')
        self.lb_currdate.config(font=('Arial', 9))
        self.lb_currdate.grid(row=0,column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        
        self.ent_currdate = tk.Entry(self.left_frame)
        self.ent_currdate.insert(tk.END, str(0))
        self.ent_currdate.grid(row=0,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

root = tk.Tk()
mywin = MyWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

I would expect the frames look the same and the label and entry will displace on top of red frame (left frame).

I am so confused about this, could someone give me a hint which line of codes are wrong?

Thank you

**#-----Update------**

Based on the suggestion, I included sticky in my grid.
It looks much better but still not 100% as what I expected. I try different combination of sticky, but none of them is correct:

**Test1 (give left frame sticky)**:

```
self.left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.N + tk.E + tk.S + tk.W)
```

[image]

the mainframe doesn't filled enti

**Test2 (give left frame and main frame both sticky)**:

```
self.main_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=0, pady=0, sticky=tk.N + tk.E + tk.S + tk.W)

self.left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.N + tk.E + tk.S + tk.W)
```

[image]

left frame and right frame doesn't fill the main frame

Comment: `sticky` option is to tell the layout manager how to occupy the available space in a row or column.  However you need to tell the layout manager *how much* space you want to allocate to a column or row by using `.rowconfigure()` and `.columnconfigure()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Making the red frame expand to fill its grid cell

The problem is that the frame automatically resizes to fit the content. To fix this, you can use the `sticky` keyword argument of the `grid` method.

```
self.left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='NESW')
```

The `'NESW'` stands for "north, east, south, west". If you prefer, you can write this as:

```
self.left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.N + tk.E + tk.S + tk.W)
```

You will need to do this for every frame that you want to behave like this.

You can also use different sticky values to produce different outcomes, e.g. if you just use `sticky=tk.S` then the frame will move to the bottom of its available space.

## Removing unwanted empty space

In order to make the frames fill the space, you can use `grid_rowconfigure` and `grid_columnconfigure` with the `weight` keyword argument. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45850468/6744133) for a full explaintion.

In short, you need to configure the grid to expand to fill the available space rather than manually specifying widths and heights. I have modified your code to do this. Note that the only time the height is specified in pixels is when the frame is not supposed to expand, namely for the `top_frame`.

```
import tkinter as tk


class MyWindow:
    def __init__(self, root: tk.Tk):
        w_root = 1280
        h_root = 720
        root.title('My model')
        root.geometry(f"{w_root}x{h_root}")

        self.top_frame = tk.Frame(root, height=80, bg='grey')
        self.top_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=0, pady=5, sticky=tk.N + tk.E + tk.S + tk.W)
        self.main_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='blue')
        root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.main_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=0, pady=0, sticky=tk.N + tk.E + tk.S + tk.W)
        self.main_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.left_frame = tk.Frame(self.main_frame, bg='red')
        self.left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.N + tk.E + tk.S + tk.W)
        self.main_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.right_frame = tk.Frame(self.main_frame, bg='yellow')
        self.right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.N + tk.E + tk.S + tk.W)
        self.main_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=2)

        self.lb_currdate = tk.Label(self.left_frame, text='my lable1:')
        self.lb_currdate.config(font=('Arial', 9))
        self.lb_currdate.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.ent_currdate = tk.Entry(self.left_frame)
        self.ent_currdate.insert(tk.END, str(0))
        self.ent_currdate.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=tk.N + tk.E + tk.S + tk.W)
        self.left_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)


root = tk.Tk()
mywin = MyWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do bear in mind that sometimes `self.left_frame.rowconfigure()` and `self.left_frame.columnconfigure()` with the `weight` argument need to be called so that the `sticky` can work. Maybe you should include that in your answer.

Comment: @Oli Your suggestion is definitely in the correct direction. But I still cannot perfectly fill the frame inside the frame. I edit the issue in my original question. Do you have any further suggestion?

Comment: @codingsnake99 Are these edits good?

Comment: Thank you so much! it works perfectly and the link you provided also help me a lot on understanding.