# Widgets in grid with sticky aren't resized with the window/frame

Tags: python, tkinter, scale

I have a window containing widgets with a grid layout, created by this code:

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

label = Label(text="that label")
label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='EW')

entry = Entry()
entry.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='EW')

window.mainloop()
```

I would expect the label and entry widget to resize with the window, but if I enlarge the window, it looks like this:

[image: window using grid manager]

If I use `pack` instead of `grid` (with the `fill` option) like so:

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

label = Label(text="that label")
label.pack(fill=X)

entry = Entry()
entry.pack(fill=X)

window.mainloop()
```

Then the enlarged window looks like this (what I would want it to look like):
[image: window using pack manager]

Why don't the widgets resize with the window when using `grid` and how do I make them do it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847313/what-does-weight-do-in-tkinter. Your question isn't an exact duplicate of that, but the answer to that question will likely answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to why the `grid` geometry manager doesn't do this automatically - I don't really know. Maybe someone can elaborate on this?

But the solution is very simple: Using `grid_columnconfigure` (or `grid_rowconfigure` respectively):

This is a function associated with a frame/window object that takes as parameters the column (or row) it modifies (can also be a list of indices or the keyword `all` for all columns/rows) and parameters to configure (see [the documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/grid.html#M8) for a detailed description).

To get the widgets to resize with their master object, the parameter `weight` has to be set to a nonzero value. Your example would look like this:

```py
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

label = Label(text="that label")
label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='EW')

entry = Entry()
entry.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='EW')

window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

window.mainloop()
```

If you run the code the label and entry widget will change size accordingly:
[image: window with columnconfigure]

Note that if you use different values for `weight` for different columns/rows, their relation will determine how the extra space gets split up between them.

Comment: _"As to why the grid geometry manager doesn't do this automatically - I don't really know. Maybe someone can elaborate on this?"_ - probably because any guess that `grid` about which rows or columns to expand will be wrong as often as it is right. It's better just to let the programmer decide.