# Python Tkinter - full width frames not working

Tags: python, tkinter

In short, I have such a code (it is a fragment, but the important one).

```
class DF(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master,width):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)

        self.root_frame = Frame(self, bg="red")
        self.root_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="ne")

        bottom_frame = Frame(self)
        bottom_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="ne")


            cancel_button = Button(master=bottom_frame)
            cancel_button.pack(side="right")
```

For example, this is how I dynamically create consecutive _main_form elements.

```
def add(self):
    label = tk.Label(master=self._main_frame)
    label.grid(row=self._rows, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="we")
```

tk.Entry(master=self._main_frame)
textbox.grid(row=self._rows, column=2, columnspan=2, sticky="ne")

However, the window does not adjust to the window's width. What can I do in such a situation? Thanks to bg you can see as if these frames were not at all in their entire width. I also add a screen.

Comment: Search for `.grid_columnconfigure` and `.grid_rowconfigure`. Also note that it is usually not a great idea to overwrite builtin-variables like `type` and that you can find a [Beginners guide on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63536506/13629335).

Comment: is `add_textbox_with_label` part of the definition of the class `DialogForm`?

Comment: yes, that's one of her methods. I create this object in another object and then I can use object.add_textbox_with_label etc.

Comment: That description is unclear. What is this other object? Could you please provide a complete example as a single block of code? Though, a cursory glance makes me thing @Thingamabobs is correct - you need to use `columnconfigure` to make sure all extra space goes to the frame.

Comment: Like on my last screenshot - columnconfigure not working as well.

Comment: Your updated code has inconsistent variable name. Should `self._main_frame` be `self.root_frame` instead?

Answer (score 2):

The root of the problem is that you're using `grid` in the `Toplevel`, but you haven't told grid what to do with extra space. As a rule of thumb, you should always call `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` to give a positive weight to at least one row and one column.

```
self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

In this case, however, since you only have two full-width frames inside the `Toplevel`, it's simpler to use `pack` for both the top and bottom frames.

```
bottom_frame.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
self._main_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

Either of those solutions solve the problem of the bottom and top frame not taking the full width of the window. You need to be equally diligent to add weight to columns and rows inside of `self._main_frame`.

For a deeper description of how the `weight` option works, along with some visual aids, see [What does 'weight' do in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847313/what-does-weight-do-in-tkinter)

Comment: I agree, pack works best for containers in general. But since OP was asking for grid I'd suggested grid configure.

Comment: @SpectrumCodeFrom: that link takes me to a sign-up page.